# Android Library: MVC Proxy vs Service

Tags: android, service, proxy

I'm making a android library project to use our API. Following MVC rules, I've created some proxies to centralize the usage of certain tasks. e.g. I have a LoginProxy which handles all the requests, data, ... involving logging in. 
To reach this, you have to call LoginProxy.getInstance().methodname. When you want to log in, you have to call the login method on the proxy, which executes a AsyncTask, executing a webservice call to a server. When the answer of the call arrives back to the LoginProxy, the LoginProxy has to dispatch an event, notifying components (Activities) about changes. At this moment, I've made my own event dispatching mechanism. Activities using this LoginProxy have to add a EventListener to an event of the LoginProxy in order to be notified about changes. I've added my LoginProxy code.

```
public class LoginProxy extends EventDispatcher implements LoginUserListener {

    private boolean loggedIn;
    private boolean loggingIn;
    private String userName;
    private UserConfiguration userConfiguration;
    private Credentials credentials; 

    private LoginProxy(){}

    /**
     * Gets a singleton instance of this class
     */
    private static LoginProxy _instance;
    public static LoginProxy getInstance(){
        if(_instance == null) {
            _instance = new LoginProxy();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return loggedIn;
    }
    private void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn) {
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
        dispatchEvent(new GeneralEvent(GeneralEventType.LOGGED_IN_CHANGED));
    }

    public boolean isLoggingIn() {
        return loggingIn;
    }
    private void setLoggingIn(boolean loggingIn) {
        this.loggingIn = loggingIn;
        dispatchEvent(new GeneralEvent(GeneralEventType.LOGGING_IN_CHANGED));
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    private void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public UserConfiguration getUserConfiguration() {
        return userConfiguration;
    }
    private void setUserConfiguration(UserConfiguration userConfiguration) {
        this.userConfiguration = userConfiguration;
    }

    public Credentials getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }
    private void setCredentials(Credentials credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    public void login(String userName, String userPassword, String applicationId, String applicationPassword, String clientVersion){
        setLoggingIn(true);
        LoginUserLauncher launcher = new LoginUserLauncher(this);
        launcher.loginUser(userName, userPassword, applicationId, applicationPassword, clientVersion);
        setUserName(userName);
    }

    public void logout(){
        setUserName(null);
        setUserConfiguration(null);
        setCredentials(null);
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginUserDone(LoginUserLauncher sender, StatusCode responseStatusCode, UserConfiguration userConfiguration, String sessionCode) {
        setLoggingIn(false);

        if(responseStatusCode == StatusCode.OK){
            setLoggedIn(true);
            setUserConfiguration(userConfiguration);
            Credentials c = new Credentials(userConfiguration.getUserID(), userConfiguration.getUserPassword(), sender.getApplicationId(), sender.getApplicationPassword(), sessionCode);
            setCredentials(c);

            dispatchEvent(new LoginEvent(LoginEventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS, responseStatusCode, this.userConfiguration));
        }else{
            setUserName(null);
            setUserConfiguration(null);
            setCredentials(null);
            setLoggedIn(false);

            dispatchEvent(new LoginEvent(LoginEventType.LOGIN_FAILED, responseStatusCode, this.userConfiguration));
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this works fine, but now I'm realizing that perhaps it's also possible to use Android Services for these proxies. Then I can send broadcasts instead of self made events. My question now is: Is it OK to use Service for these proxies? If so, I suppose that I have to make a aidl interface for binding?

Can anyone help me with this matter? 
Thanks